# «Накося выкуси» — оформление фразеологизма

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, фразеология, просторечия

Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка:
[**Накось (накося) выкуси!**](https://phraseology.academic.ru/7007/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C_%28%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%29_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%21)
Грубо-прост. Ничего не добьёшься, не получишь, не рассчитывай. *Пальцы Грузова сложились в символический знак и приблизились вплоть к длинному носу остзейца. — **Накось, выкуси!*** (Куприн. На переломе). *— Жить живите, а уж насчёт корма — **накося выкуси!** — сказал Зотов, впуская их. — Хоть околевайте* (Чехов. Нахлебники).

В словарной статье в одном из примеров фразеологизм представлен с запятой, в другом — без.
В [Нацкорпусе](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&g=i_doc&dpp=10&spp=50&text=lexform&req=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8&kwsz=5&mode=main&sr=1&spd=10&nodia=1&out=normal) — тоже по-разному (есть даже с дефисом).
А кабы мне рублей ста полтора заробить, сейчас бы я на ноги встал и ― Антипу-то ― **накося, выкуси!** [Максим Горький. Челкаш (1894)]
Зверье всякое видывал, а что насчет страшного ― **накося выкуси!** [А. П. Чехов. На большой дороге (1885)]
А тот, в лисьей поддевке и бобровой шапке, показал им кукиш: ― **Накося ― выкуси!** Доделай сперва! [В. А. Гиляровский. Козел и «чайка» (1933-1935)]

Подскажите-разъясните, пожалуйста: а как правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Значение слова**

**НАКОСЬ; НАКОСЯ.** Нар.-разг. I. частица. **На**, возьми что-л. **Накося** пирожок. II. в зн. **вводн. сл.** Выражает удивление или осуждение; подумать только. **Накось,** какой умный нашёлся! **Накося,** что в газетах пишут! ◊ **Накось выкуси!** Ничего не получишь, ничего не добьёшься.

Также: **НА**, частица. Разг. Возьми, бери. На, возьми книгу, передай брату. Передай мне масло. - На, дорогой. ◊ Вот тебе (и) на!; Вот те (и) на! Восклицание по поводу чего-л. неожиданного (обычно неприятного) события, происшествия. **На** тебе! Употр. для выражения удивления или недовольства кем-, чем-л. **На-ка выкуси!**

**2. Как пишется**

Писать надо в соответствии со словарем и  другими источниками.

**Вопрос № 200978.**
Здравствуйте. Я отправлял Вам вопрос о корректном написании словосочетания "накуси - выкуси". К сожалению, ответа не были, видимо что-то неправильно сработало. Если можно, прошу вас дать ответ. С уважением.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Правильно: ***накось выкуси*** и ***накося выкуси.***

3. В литературе встречается написание с запятой и тире. Такое написание не кажется логичным для фразеологического сочетания, но оно может  быть **интонационным,** если сделать паузу в речи по аналогии с «на», «на-ка». Но тогда лучше использовать **запятую.**  В любом случае такое оформление будет **авторским.**

Сравнить: ***На**, бери и прячь. **На-ка**, выпей сначала с устатку.  **На-ка** пока деньги, да не перепутай ― в этом кармане будут несчитанные.*

К тому же приходится учитывать, что запятая используется при обособлении вводного слова: II. в зн. **вводн. сл.** Выражает удивление или осуждение; подумать только. **Накось,** какой умный нашёлся! **Накося**, что в газетах пишут!